How can I understand the output of cross_val_predict?
I have the following lines
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, as_frame=False)


X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)


rom sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3, random_state=42)


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train_5, cv=3)

I understand the last line splits the data set into three parts. The algorithm employs 2 for training and one for validation. This is then repeated 3 times changing the training and validation sets. A similar piece of code using cross_val_score outputs array([0.95035, 0.96035, 0.9604 ])as expected: three numbers, one for each validation. For cross_val_predict i would expect something similar, but len(y_train_pred) indicates 60000 and i dont understand why. So, how does cross_val_predict works?

Does this answer your question? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html

OK, yes I can see "Generate cross-validated estimates for each input data point" so this clarifies why the length of the output is 60000. Thanks
